# Google maps night mode embed iframe

Tags: google-maps

I want to embed a Google map night mode using iframe, I saw some code which can done using Google maps API, but does anyone know is that able to embed maps night mode using simple iframe?

[image]

Comment: Also check out the styling wizard with ready made styles: https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, styling, such as is needed to implement night mode, is not available through the Embed API.  As you point out, it is available through the JS API.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Answer (score 22):

You can use CSS filter invert():

```
<iframe style="filter: invert(90%)" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?..."></iframe>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this messes up the satellite view

Comment: for me it messed up the satellite view as well, however also adding: height: 100vh to the style fixed it

Comment: With `filter: invert(90%) grayscale(1)` it looks pretty good.

Comment: Or keep the colors with: `filter: invert(90%) hue-rotate(180deg)`

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS, there is official google api to do this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/style-array

Comment: @insider The question was about **embed api** but the offical google api you suggested was for **javascript api** and it is not usable in embed api.

Answer (score 3):

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.map{
  height: 100vh;
  filter: grayscale(100%) invert(92%) contrast(83%);
}
```

```html
<iframe class="map"
        
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d63480.847337751366!2d80.211997!3d6.055892!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3ae173bb6932fce3%3A0x4a35b903f9c64c03!2sGalle%2C%20Sri%20Lanka!5e0!3m2!1sen!2ssg!4v1673338264656!5m2!1sen!2ssg" 
        
width="100%" height="324" frameborder="0" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" aria-hidden="false" tabindex="0"></iframe>
```